# Laravel pluck but combining first name + last name for select

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, jquery-select2

Using select2 with a Laravel / Vue project and need to return JSON in the following format:

```
[
    { id: 0, text: 'enhancement' },
    { id: 1, text: 'bug' }
]
```

In Laravel I know I can use pluck to create my list data e.g. for customers:

```
$customers = Customer::pluck('id', 'first_name');
```

But Want to return the id and first name + last name as a single name.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried using Accessors?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

I have not tested it but this could work:

add this to your Customer Eloquent Model:

```
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
       return ucfirst($this->first_name) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->last_name);
    }
```

and then try:

**UPDATED** pluck on accessor will only work on a collection. If you try `Customer::pluck('id', 'full_name')` it will not work since there is no db column named full_name, therefore you must use `Customer::all()->pluck('full_name', 'id')`

```
$customers = Customer::all()->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```

- as a side note, for performance it is probably better to do `Customer::all(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])->pluck(...)` so that we don't pull unnecessary columns from the db.

Hope this helps.

**Updated Date:- 26th Aug, 2021**
If we use **computed Attribute [accessor functionality](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)**, then mind it one important thing...

Laravel Accessor functionality works after the Data fetched from DataBase. So we have to declare **"pluck(accessorName)" at the end of Query....**

For Example:-

**Wrong Methods:-**

```
$data = Model::pluck('full_name','id)->get(); 
$data = Model::pluck('full_name','id)->all();
```

> **in above two queries if you does not have full_name field in DataTable you will get Unknown column error**

**Right Methods:-**

```
$data = Model::get()->pluck('full_name','id');
$data = Model::all()->pluck('full_name','id');
```

> **in above two queries it will works perfectly even if you doesn't have full_name field in DataTable**

Comment: thank you for the explanation that this would only work on a collection, the very reason why it is not working on me. upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this,

```
$customers = DB::table('customers')->select("id", "CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) as fullname")->get();
```

or you also do like this,

```
$customers = DB::table('customers')->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) as fullname, id'))->get();
```

or with PHP way,

```
$fullname = $customers->firstname. " " .$customers->lastname;
```

Comment: it gives me SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CONCAT...

Answer (score 3):

Set this in the User model

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

Then make sure you add this too

```
protected $appends = ['full_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked

```
\DB::table("admin as c")->select(\DB::raw("CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS FIRSTNAME"),"c.AdminID")->pluck("FIRSTNAME","AdminID");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. Hope it will work. And I solve this problem using this code

```
User::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name"),"id")->pluck("full_name","id");
```

Answer (score 0):

User Model :

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

Get query will result in collection :

```
$agents = User::whereId($agent->id)->get()->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```

Inorder to convert variable from objects to array :

```
  $agents = json_decode(json_encode($agents), true);
```

It worked for me.Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /**
 * Get the full name of the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

and use this pluck

```
User::all()->sortBy('id')->pluck('full_name', 'id')
```

like this

```
   public static function list()
{
    return Cache::tags('usersCustomers')->rememberForever(md5('usersCustomers.list:' . locale()), function () {
        return self::all()->sortBy('id')->pluck('full_name', 'id');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

** Use this code. Hope it will work. And I solve this problem using this code**

```
       User::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS 
       full_name"),"id")->pluck("full_name","id");
```