# How to use laravel accessor in trait?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, traits, accessor

I would like to put accessor in trait, and for some reason this is not working (I have current applocale in session):

Trait:

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait TranslateEntities
{
 public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        if (session('applocale')=='en')
        {
            return $value;
        } else {
            return trans("entities.".$this->code);
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\TranslateEntities;

class Repairstatus extends \Eloquent {

    use TranslateEntities;

    (...)
}
```

This way I'm not getting translated entity, but if I put this `public function getNameAttribute($value)` inside model, it works ok.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution here:
[Laravel pluck but combining first name + last name for select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475537/laravel-pluck-but-combining-first-name-last-name-for-select)
Problem is in "pluck" method, not having "code" attribute...